# Swift - How to get row data from custom UITableViewCell on UIImageView click from within the cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I’m trying to get data associated with the `UITableViewCell` where a `UIImageView` is clicked within the cell. The code I currently have to capture the click event is working fine. However, once I get into the click function that is called, I’m unable to retrieve the associated data from the same `UITableViewCell` where the `UIImageView` was clicked. Here is the code I'm using to set up the click event. This code is contained in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
    var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("staticMap_click:"))
    cell.imgStaticMap.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    cell.imgStaticMap.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Here is the function `staticMap_click` that gets called when the `UIImageView` is clicked:

```
func staticMap_click(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    let rowData: NSDictionary = self.arrayPosts[sender.valueForKey("row") as Int] as NSDictionary

    mdblStaticLat = rowData["dblLat"] as String
    mdblStaticLong = rowData["dblLong"] as String
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("sgShowMapFromStaticClick", sender: self)
}
```

As you can see, I'm unsure of how to reference the data for the row that was clicked. I attempted setting a tag on the `UIImageView`, but that didn’t work. I also attempted to set a tag on the `UITapGestureRecognizer`, but I haven’t been able to get that to work either.

Does anyone know how I can reference the data from the selected row where the `UIImageView` is tapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
}
```

This function will be called whenever a cell is pressed.
You can access the row which is pressed by using `indexPath.row`

Furthermore you can use

```
func staticMap_click(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    let tappedView = sender.view as? UIImageView
    let indexPath = (tappedView.superview as UITableView).indexPathForCell(self)
}
```

To get the cell which was tapped if you want only the Image to be tapable

This code will also return an indexPath, you will be able to use `indexPath.row` again to get the row.
Getting the row will enable you to get data out of an array if deemed necessary

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll give that a try and report back the results.

Comment: As far as I can tell, using didDeselectRowAtIndexPath would only be useful if I wanted to capture an event click just on the row rather than on the UIImageView within the row. Am I correct?  If not, how could I capture a click on the UIImageView by using didDeselectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: You are correct, hopefully my update to the answer will help you

Comment: @play2win Did this actually work for you? This expression, `tappedView.superview as UITableView` shouldn't have worked. The image view's superview certainly isn't the table view -- it's not even the cell. Its superview should be the cell's contentView.